# How i can check MariaDB is Standard or Enterprise Edition

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.5.13. Need to confirm is my database is enterprise or standard edition?

Checked google and [I need to know if they have an ENTERPRISE or COMMUNITY MYSQL edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147413/i-need-to-know-if-they-have-an-enterprise-or-community-mysql-edition) found below SQL Query:

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

When i execute above query in version_comment i am getting MariaDB Server.

[image]

So can you help me here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the community server.

Enterprise server has versions like:

- 10.5.15-10
- 10.5.13-9

ref: [Enterprise server documentation](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/repo/cli/mariadb_es_repo_setup/mariadb-server-version/).