# How to exactly determine if a given MariaDB installation is the free or the commercial version?

Tags: mariadb

**Context**

I am executing the following command: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`
and getting the following output:

```
| version                           | 10.10.2-MariaDB                          |
| version_comment                   | MariaDB Server                           |
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I was trying to google on [mariadb version_comment] and [this (official MariaDB)](https://mariadb.com/docs/skysql/ref/mdb/system-variables/version_comment/) is not helping...

**Question**

How can I determine if this installation is the free or the commercial version?

Comment: not sure if it helps but same question on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466706/how-i-can-check-mariadb-is-standard-or-enterprise-edition

Comment: many thx, I've already found and read that at the time I posted my question, it does not help, because specific to one version, and also not documented...